# Using Open ID with Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid, google-apps-marketplace, google-api-js-client

We are using Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript to work with Google Drive. Going [regular OAUTH2 way](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#Authexample), shows user an authorization dialog (only for the first time, but that is enough) and promtpt for access to google drive. The [Google Marketplace checklist](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/testing#openid_whitelist) requires that the application used OpenId realm for seamless Singel Sign On, to make application whitelisted and **not to** promtp user for access explicitly, but leave the access management to domain administrator.

So my question is how to make work together Open ID and  Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript, when all documentation for the latter library discribes only work with OAUTH2?

Comment: The checklist is no longer valid as we (Google) just launched a new experience for the Google Apps Marketplace which exclusively uses OAuth2 and does not require OpenID. Learn more at https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/.